# Is it possible to develop iOS App on windows using (Xamarin and visual studio) without MAC

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have already developed android app using xamarin and now i want to do same for iOS. As per xamarin's official documentation, i need to have MAC machine to compile my C# code, but i dont have MAC. Is there any workaround or alternative so that i can build ios app using xamarin without need of MAC.

Comment: "a Mac is required to compile the .ipk file, and applications cannot be deployed to a device without Apple’s certificates and code-signing tools. The iOS simulator can also only be used on a Mac."

Comment: Can i use iPhone to build?

Comment: I believe the xcode toolchain required only works on actual OSX.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Xamarin-Development-using-Visual-Studio-4971276.S.5935501398127951874?trk=groups_items_see_more-0-b-ttl

Answer (score 4):

No.  The underlying SDK and build tools, including the iOS simulator, are provided by Apple and will only run on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cloud Mac service [Macincloud](http://www.macincloud.com) which supports Xamarin remote build from Visual Studio. You will not be able to build iOS Apps without a Mac so [Macincloud](http://www.macincloud.com) is your best alternative.

Answer (score 0):

As standard Xcode only runs on UNIX/OSX.
However it IS possible to run Mac OSX, in order to develop iOS apps, with software such as VMWare and Parallels - But I won't recommend it in any way.